# Increment a floating point number HTML/JavaScript

Tags: html, floating-point, increment

I'm using these functions to increment/decrement slider variable by 1.

```html
function tstatUP()
{
 var newValue = document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML;
 newValue++;
 if(newValue > 86) newValue = 86;
 document.getElementById("tstatRange2").value = newValue;
 document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML = newValue;
}

function tstatDN()
{
    var newValue = document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML;
 newValue--;
 if(newValue < 72) newValue = 72;
 document.getElementById("tstatRange2").value = newValue;
 document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML = newValue;
}
```

but if I replace newValue++; with newValue+=0.5; I see undefined behavior when range2 updates:

[image: Note the wonky decimal]

as if it is being treated like a String.

I'm not experienced with HTML... here is the button HTML:

```html
<div id="tstatSlider">
    
      <h2>Thermostat Setting</h2>
      <input id="tstatRange2" type="range" style="width: 200px; height 40px" min="72.0" max="86.0" value="76" step = "0.5" list="increments2" oninput="showMainTstatValue(this.value)" onchange="showMainTstatValue(this.value)">
      <datalist id="increments2">
       <option>72</option>
       <option>74</option>
       <option>76</option>
       <option>78</option>
       <option>80</option>
       <option>82</option>
       <option>84</option>
       <option>86</option>
      </datalist>
      <span id="range2">76.0</span>&deg;F
      <br/> <br/>
      <input type="button" class="button" onclick="sendMainTstatValue()" value = SUBMIT />
      <br /><br />
     </div>
     
     <div id="tstatButtons">
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="button" class="button" value="UP" onclick="tstatUP()">
      <br />
      <input type="button" class="button" value="DOWN" onclick="tstatDN()">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because innerHTML is returning you a String, the newValue++ operator is parsing internally to a number but the += is a valid operator on a string since you can make concatenations with it (therefore is being treated as a String):

```
var x = "foo" 
x += "bar"; //This shoud be "foobar"
```

You just need to parse the value as a float number (using parseFloat) before manipulating it so it's treated as a number instead:

```
var newValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML);
```

here is a fiddle with the solution: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tfoodt2w/)

Here is the updated function

```html
function tstatUP()
{
 var newValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML);
 newValue+=0.5;
 if(newValue > 86) newValue = 86;
 document.getElementById("tstatRange2").value = newValue;
 document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML = newValue;
}

function tstatDN()
{
    var newValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML);
 newValue-=0.5;
 if(newValue < 72) newValue = 72;
 document.getElementById("tstatRange2").value = newValue;
 document.getElementById("range2").innerHTML = newValue;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to say thanks for the help earlier, but I was in China and for some reason, I could not get through the Great Firewall to StackOverflow... cannot understand why they's block this site.

Comment: No problem @JimfromPrinceton, please select this as the answer if this solved your doubt.